# I need to make "EF Core 2.1.0" remove white space from Strings fields in queries, "HasConversion" not is not working, can you tell me why?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, db2, trim

I added the overload function "Cofigure" whith "HasConversion" applied to "aply configuration", but it is not working, can you tell me why?

-using DB2 database

```
entity.Property(c => c.Unidade).HasColumnName("UNIDADE")
                .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<string, string>(v => v.TrimEnd(), v => v.TrimEnd()));
```

Query:

```
public List<ItemServico> List()
        {
            return _uow._db.ItensServico.ToList();
        }
```

[Result still with spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1e13I.png)

Comment: would it not be more pragmatic to just trim them *after* fetching them? or even better: before *storing* them (and fix the existing data)?

Comment: I am not the one who populates the database and all text fields are like this.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on `v.TrimEnd()`, is it ever hit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263948/how-can-i-configure-entity-framework-to-automatically-trim-values)