# How can I configure Entity Framework to automatically trim values?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, db2, ef-core-2.1

I need to make “EF Core 2.1.0” remove white space from Strings fields in queries, “HasConversion” not is not working, can you tell me why?

```
entity.Property(e => e.Name)
             .HasConversion(
                new ValueConverter<string, string>(v => v.TrimEnd(), v => v.TrimEnd()));
```

-using DB2 database and .net core 2.1

Query:

```
public List<ItemServico> List()
        {
            return _uow._db.ItensServico.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what the `varchar` type is for, to trim spaces automatically, and efficiently.

Manual `trim()` operations have to loop over the string every time to figure out the useful data, whereas `varchar` simply stores the useful length.

In general, you'll find that EF Core has moved to remove the more useless functions in an effort to implement the useful functions in as efficient as manner as possible. Especially later EF Core versions (you're 3 versions behind).

Comment: ANSI standard requires storing trailing spaces but ignoring them in comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

If you use EF Core and want to avoid the whitespace issue, simply use the `varchar(n)`
data type in SQL, in EF Core `Char(n)`
types produce whitespace.

Comment: This is exactly what the other answer said and exactly the same comment applies. Using (n)varchar does not trim values.